# JPA, store an Entity with ManyToOne foreign keys

Tags: jpa, many-to-one

I have succesfully create an Entity (and the corresponding data table) like the following one:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS_BOOK")
public class UsersBook {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator =     "USERS_BOOK_SQ")
private long              id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
private Room            room;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
private Building        building;
```

It creates a table with 2 foreign keys (room_id and building_id) to the corresponding Entities (Room and Building).

Now I'd like to store a new UsersBook linked with a Room and a Building, already stored on my db.

I already know the primary keys (ID) of a row in the Room table and Building table.

How I can tell JPA to use the foreign key I already have for Room and Building?

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EntityManager.find()` (to actually find them in the database) or `EntityManager.getReference()` (to get an unitialized proxy, assuming that they do exist in the database):

```
Room room = em.getReference(Room.class, roomId);
Building building = em.getReference(Building.class, buildingId);
UsersBook book = new UsersBook();
book.setRoom(room);
book.setBuilding(building);
em.persist(book);
```